# comparing array of objects and assigning similarity score

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to compare two array of object and assigning them a similarity score based of common items in the array.

I was able to compare the arrays but I am running into issue with using the same concept on array of objects.

```js
let array1 = [{key1:['item1','item2','item3','item4']},{key2:['event3','event4']}];
let array2 = [{key1:['item1','item4','item2','item8']},{key2:['event4','event2']}];

let arrayA=['item1','item2','item3','item4'];
let arrayB=['item1','item4','item2','item8'];
function SimilarityPercentage(arrayA,arrayB){
  let answer =arrayA.filter(function(item) {
     return arrayB.indexOf(item) >= 0;
  }).length
  return answer/(Math.max(arrayA.length,arrayB.length))*100
}
console.log(SimilarityPercentage(arrayA,arrayB));// 75
```

Given array1 and array2 , I would like the result split out a similarity score, similar to the function above. I would like to use the rand index calculation : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rand_index#targetText=The%20Rand%20index%20or%20Rand,is%20the%20adjusted%20Rand%20index.

Comment: do you want to get all items of the array with objects?

Comment: i have added the expected result.

Comment: it's not my data set. what is going into the calculation from the arrays with objects?

Comment: has the data set the same key on each index? does the objetc contains only one key/value pair?

Answer (score 3):

You could get the values and calculate the common score.

```js
function similarityPercentage(arrayA, arrayB) {            
    return 100 * arrayA.filter(Set.prototype.has, new Set(arrayB)).length / Math.max(arrayA.length, arrayB.length);
}

function similarities(a, b) {
    var parts = a.map((o, i) => similarityPercentage(Object.values(o)[0], Object.values(b[i])[0]));
    return parts.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / parts.length;
}

var array1 = [{ key1: ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4'] }, { key2: ['event3', 'event4'] }],
    array2 = [{ key1: ['item1', 'item4', 'item2', 'item8'] }, { key2: ['event4', 'event2'] }],
    arrayA = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4'],
    arrayB = ['item1', 'item4', 'item2', 'item8'];

console.log(similarityPercentage(arrayA, arrayB)); // 75
console.log(similarities(array1, array2));         // 62.5
```

Comment: Welp you have a better answer, I guess I can't complain. Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
var array1 = [val1,val2,val3];
var array2 = [val1,val4,val5];
var sim = [];
var simscore = 9;

if (array1.length > array2.length) {
      for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
            if(array1[i] == array2[i]) {
                   sim.push(i);
                   simarr = array1;
                   simscore ++;
             }
       }
}else{
       for (var i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
            if(array1[i] == array2[i]) {
                   sim.push(i);
                   simarr = array2;
                   simscore ++;
             }
       }
}
console.log(sim);
console.log("Percent similar: ", simscore/simarr.length);
```

This will add the similar index to an array `sim` and increase the count of similar indexes by 1, always for the longer array, then print the percent of similarity.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your sample arrays are not well-structured, and your problem can be done more quickly if you restructure them.

Since you have not provided a formula for calculating the similarity between *array1* and *array2*, I assume that every each of these arrays has equal length, and every item in them represents an object which has only one property (with the same name), and that property itself is an array. One obvious approach is to calculate every similarity score of the related child arrays of these two arrays to be calculated and then calculate the total similarity by averaging every key's similarity score.

Assumptions:

- *array1* and *array2* have equal length
- The *nth* element of *array1* has only one property with the name *keyFoo* and the *nth* element of *array2* also has only one property with the name *keyFoo* and *keyFoo* property of these two arrays are arrays themselves and must be compared to each other.

This quickly can be done using already provided `SimilarityPercentage` function:

```js
function SimilarityPercentage2 (array1, array2) {
  let similaritySum = 0;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    const elem = array1[i];
    
    const key = Object.keys(elem)[0];
    
    similaritySum += SimilarityPercentage(elem[key], array2[i][key]);
  }
  
  return similaritySum / array1.length;
}

console.log(SimilarityPercentage2(array1, array2));
// output: 62.5
```